# Multiple comparison with genotype data

Tags: multiple-comparisons, genetics

I am looking at the effect of genotype on a continuous variable. In total 16 comparisons were done involving 9 different SNPs. The number of significant events was 3 out of 16 tests (Mann-Whitney U-test). Is it necessary to correct the p-values to account for multiple comparisons?

Comment: Haven't you find anything relevant by looking at our questions with the [tag:multiple-comparisons] tag? If not, could you clarify where you are having difficulties?

Answer (score 1):

Moderator chl is right to say that there are a wealth of discussion of multiple comparisons on this site that should provide a satisfactory answer to your question. But if you are just looking for a simple yes/no answer.  The answer is yes.  I would simply add that methods for p-value adjustment for the FDR criteria is most commonly used for your problem.  See the book by [Westfall and Young](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471557617) for resampling approaches to p-value adjustment.